# Divide and conquer matrix multiplication base case + how to split matrix into 4 quarters

Tags: java, matrix, multiplication, divide-and-conquer

I've been trying to code the divide and conquer matrix multiplication algorithm

There's problem that when I try to divide matrix into four quarters it gives me an error ArrayOutOfIndexBound

- I'm not sure if I'm right about the base case, so can you help me out guys?

The problem that I get is at **double[][] a21**

```
    public static double[][] divideAndConquer(double[][] a , double[][] b, int dimension){

if (a.length == 1){
    double[][] result = new double[1][1];
    result[0][0]= a[0][0]*b[0][0];
    return result;
}
else {
    int m = dimension/2;
    double[][] a11 = new double[m][m];
    for(int i = 0; i < m ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j< m ; j++)
            a11[i][j]= a[i][j];
    }

              double[][] a21 = new double[m][m];
            for(int i = m; i < dimension; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j< m ; j++)
            a21[i][j]= a[i][j];
    }
     double[][] a12 = new double[m][m];
            for(int i = 0; i < m ; i++){
        for (int j = m ; j< dimension ; j++)
            a12[i][j]= a[i][j];
    }



    double[][] a22 = new double[m][m];
            for(int i = m; i < dimension; i++){
        for (int j =  m; j < dimension; j++)
            a21[i][j]= a[i][j];
    }


    double[][] b11 = new double[m][m];
    for(int i = 0; i < m ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j< m ; j++)
            b11[i][j]= b[i][j];
    }

     double[][] b12 = new double[m][m];
            for(int i = 0; i < m ; i++){
        for (int j = m ; j< dimension ; j++)
            b12[i][j]= b[i][j];
    }

      double[][] b21 = new double[m][m];
            for(int i = m; i < dimension; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j< m ; j++)
            b21[i][j]= b[i][j];
    }

    double[][] b22 = new double[m][m];
            for(int i = m; i < dimension; i++){
        for (int j =  m; j < dimension; j++)
            b21[i][j]= b[i][j];
    }

            double[][] x1 = divideAndConquer(a11,b11,m);
            double[][] x2 = divideAndConquer(a12,b21,m);
            double[][] x3 = divideAndConquer(a11,b12,m);
            double[][] x4 = divideAndConquer(a12,b22,m);
            double[][] x5 = divideAndConquer(a21,b11,m);
            double[][] x6 = divideAndConquer(a22,b21,m);
            double[][] x7 = divideAndConquer(a21,b12,m);
            double[][] x8 = divideAndConquer(a22,b22,m);
        ..........................etc
```

Comment: You divided into quadrants so you can implement Strassen's algorithm for big matrices later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your problem is that you need to subtract off the array offset; e.g.,

```
a12[i][j]= a[i][j];
```

should be

```
a12[i][j-dimension]= a[i][j];
```

Your bigger problem is that you're creating 4 new submatrices, which is going to generate *tons* of garbage.  Once you've gotten this working, I would strongly think about ways of doing this "in-place" by manipulating array indexes.

E.g., your new api would look like

```
public static double[][] divideAndConquer(double[][] a , double[][] b, int aMinIndex, int aMaxIndex, int bMinIndex, bMaxIndex){
```

and your divide and conquer would build subsets of the min & max indices.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. The API I kinda have to stuck with it. What about the base case? is it right? or should I make it a multiplication of 2×2 matrices?

Comment: @HamadBinAbdullah - 1) You can have the new API as a helper function, and have the default API call the helper with the appropriate arguments.  2) I'd probably base case it out to 2x2.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this for the partitioning? Please consider that it's in C and N/2 is the block size of each partition

```
for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N / 2; j++) {

        ha11[i][j] = hA[i][j]; // top left
        ha12[i][j] = hA[i][j + N / 2]; // top right
        ha21[i][j] = hA[i + N / 2][j]; // bottom left
        ha22[i][j] = hA[i + N / 2][j + N / 2]; // bottom right

        hb11[i][j] = hB[i][j]; // top left
        hb12[i][j] = hB[i][j + N / 2]; // top right
        hb21[i][j] = hB[i + N / 2][j]; // bottom left
        hb22[i][j] = hB[i + N / 2][j + N / 2]; // bottom right
    }
}
```